# XGBoost for the beginner: What are the differencies between 3 pairs of features in XGBoost?

Tags: xgboost

Would you help me, please, to differenciate some XGBoost features (below). Thank you so much.

1. what are the differencies between:

> -xgb.train
>
> -xgb.fit

Don’t they both train the model?

2. what are the differencies between:

> ```
> -num_round = 20 # The number of rounds for boosting
> -n_estimators – quantity of the trees
> ```

Don’t they both generate number of trees?

3. what are the differenceies between:

> ```
> -eta – step size
> -max_depth - depth of the tree
> ```

Don’t they both prevent overfitting?

Answer (score 0):

ad. 1

- `xgboost.train` is an xgboost method
- `.train` is a sklearn function

ad.2

similarly,

- `num_round` comes from the xgboost python api
- `n_estimators` is used in sklearn

ad. 3

- `Eta` is a parameter that controls for how much are the weights updated in each iteration.
- `Max-depth` is the upper limit on the size of each tree. Both can play role in preventing overfitting, but you need to tune them to find a combination of those two that will work with your dataset.

Please read more on the xgboost algorithm. This is intro to xgboost in R, but it has a very nice brief theoretical introduction https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/machine-learning-algorithms/beginners-tutorial-on-xgboost-parameter-tuning-r/tutorial/

Comment: Adamik Ewert, thank you very much. I will read the article you recommended. But 1st question is still remains: what is the difference between -xgb.train and -xgb.fit (not with .train and xgboost.train).